# read line from txt file to rename server - powershell

Tags: file, powershell, text

I'm trying to read a certain line from a text file using powershell, which can then be used to run with netdom to rename each DC.  The line is always line number 3 and starts with `Servername=` . I need to grab the text after the equals sign to then use with netdom.  It was working at first, but netdom would complain about the syntax.  Is this because it is a string?. Now servername is returned as the full line:

```
C:\config.txt:3:ServerName servername
```

and not just the servername.

```
 $servername = Select-String -Path "C:\config.txt" -Pattern "servername="
 $servername = $servername.tostring().split("=")
 netdom renamecomputer localhost /NewName:$servername /force
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to append [1] to the second line in order to select the split string that you need i.e:

```
$servername = $servername.tostring().split("=")[1]
```